# Url Params not accepting lengthy strings

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, wcf

While sending the image to Web server along with data it is not accepting the lengthy strings. I am sending the data through url. its working good with smaller strings for country,continent and city

```
    http://user.co/UserImage.svc/InsertObjectImage?UserId={UserId}&CategoryId={CategoryId}&ImageName={ImageName}&Gender={Gender}&Continent={Continent}&Country={Country}&City={City}
```

The above url am using in program upto "?", after that it is with params

```
    NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://userdata.co.in/UserImage.svc/InsertFacialImage?%@",requestString];
    NSLog(@"insert facial image url : %@",url);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

The code I am using to send the image along with data.Here am passing strings with url.Objective-C NSString can hold the data up to 4.2Billion characters. In the web server the I made it to allow 200 characters for param. But when I am sending the lengthy string like **united states of america** its making the trouble not storing the data.Services developed in WCF using C#

Comment: There are length limitations to URLs but it is also worth checking that your URL is valid. To check, you are actually passing `united%20states%20of%20america` in your URL string? So URL encoding spaces to `%20` (and other special characters of course)?

Comment: thanq @Belogix its solved

Comment: I have posted as an answer to help other people in future. Please could you review and mark. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are length limitations to URLs but it is also worth checking that your URL is valid.

URLs need to be correctly encoded so you should be passing `united%20states%20of%20america` in your URL string rather than `united states of america`.

This is because URL encodes spaces to `%20`. For any other "special" characters these are also encoded. There are many online resource that should help you and a quick online encoder / decoder can be found here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/